# how the memory allocation in an recurssion is alloted

Tags: c, recursion, compilation

```
int fact(int x)
{
    if (x == 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return (x * fact(x-1));
}
```

My question is how the variables are allotted on the stack during function call and if `x = 5` - obviously the return would be `5 * fact(4)`, but how this `5 * fact(4)` is pushed onto the stack how its value is resolved later i.e simple values (not variables) can be pushed and their values can be retrieved back, but how does the compiler treat `fact(4)`. 
Can anyone explain how exactly this recursion procedure is implemented by the compiler in detail?

Answer (score 3):

Before `5 * fact(4)` is returned `fact(4)` is called and evaluated on a new stack frame.  When the call to `fact(4)` finishes, it places it's return value where the `fact(5)` stack frame can reach it (this may be the stack or in a register) and use it to calculate its own return value.  So the order of finishing evaluation will be `fact(1)`, `fact(2)`, ..., `fact(4)`, `fact(5)`.  Each placing their return values where the next one can retrieve it and use to calculate its own return value.